# How to Verify a dynamic JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON Object that has a body part which I parse. However, The body can have a few potential outcomes based on the API ran. I can either receive in the body something like this:

```
body: '{"OrderNumber":"123123123","ExtraInfo":[]}'
```

or something like this:

```
body: '{"error":"Something went wrong"}' }
```

When I parse my object I do `var temp=JSON.parse(object.body)`. How can I verify which type of body did I get - meaning if its `body.OrderNumber` or `body.error` ? I'd need to identify the contents of body in order to determine my next step.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check if `body.error` is undefined.  If undefined then you have a non-error response.  Otherwise its an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function test(object) {
  var temp=JSON.parse(object.body);
  if (temp.error) {
     console.log(temp.error); // display error message
  } else {
     console.log("Success");
     console.log(temp.OrderNumber); // display result
  }
}

var object1 = {'body': '{"OrderNumber":"123123123","ExtraInfo":[]}'}
var object2 = {'body': '{"error":"Something went wrong"}'}

test(object1);
test(object2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` method to check if the property is available to an object or not -

```
if(temp.hasOwnProperty('error') ) {
 // Show error
}
else if( temp.hasOwnProperty('OrderNumber') ) {
 // Show something
}
else {
 // Show what you want
}
```

Comment: Hey man, You were the first to reply but the guy after you gave me something I liked better. I hope you'll be satisfied at least with an upvote :) Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if(body.error) {
  //logic if error is not defined 
} else {
  //your logic if there is error in body
}
```